# ngNewRouter Angularjs 1.4.4 is not able to call component controller methods after callback

Tags: angularjs, callback, controller, angular-routing

Today I was working to migrate my existing Angular js ngRoute base code to ngNewRouter and got stuck in component controller. As per new apporach component controller doesn't have $scope, instead of it uses "this". It works fine for simple usecase. In my usecase for a particular component I make REST API call to get the data. All works but when callback happens then it is not identifying "this" defined object. Following is code snippet for more details.

Component Controller to make call to get data:

```
var ClubonboardingController = function ($location, ApplicationLoaderService, ApplicationConstants, $window, ResourceImplementation, $rootScope) {
    //Launch Application
    this.launchApplication = function () {
        this.cacheLoaded = true;
    };


    //Method to initialize 
    this.init = function () {            
            //show loading screen
            this.showLoadingScreen = true;                   
            //Initilize Application cache
            ApplicationLoaderService.initilizeApplicationCache($rootScope, "3252345", true, "en_US", function () {
                this.launchApplication(); //This throws function not found exception
            });

    };

    //Call init() to initialze the loading.
    this.init();    
};

app.controller("ClubonboardingController", ClubonboardingController);
ClubonboardingController.$inject = ['$location', 'ApplicationLoaderService', 'ApplicationConstants', '$window', 'ResourceImplementation', '$rootScope'];
```

Issue: After callback code thinks "this" as global javascript object, instead of "this" for this controller and not able to find anything defines in this controller and it throw exception at this.launchApplication(); .

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that what 'this' means changes depending on context. There seems to be a general recommendation to assign 'this' to a local variable and use the variable. Thanks to JavaScript closures, the value of 'this' is then retained.

Using a local variable called vm seems to be common, and replace all 'this.' with 'vm.' Your code would end up changing to

```
var ClubonboardingController = function ($location, ApplicationLoaderService, ApplicationConstants, 
                                     $window, ResourceImplementation, $rootScope) {
var vm = this;

 //Launch Application
vm.launchApplication = function () {
    vm.cacheLoaded = true;
};

//Method to initialize 
vm.init = function () {
    ...
```

Hope this helps.